# Python perform byte-wise operations on short, not int

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, crc, short

How do I write the following C program in Python? The issue is that Python considers `crc` is an `int`, not a `short`, and thus the result is complete nonsense...

```c
unsigned short special_crc16(volatile unsigned char *sbuf,unsigned int len){
    unsigned short crc=0xFFFF;

    while(len){
        crc=(unsigned char)(crc >> 8) | (crc << 8);
        crc^=(unsigned char) *sbuf;
        crc^=(unsigned char)(crc & 0xff) >> 4;
        crc^=(crc << 8) << 4;
        crc^=((crc & 0xff) << 4) << 1;
        len--;
        sbuf++;
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Input: `8C 4C`
Expected output: `CA B2`

My Python 3 attempt:

```py
def compute(data, datalen):
    crc=0xFFFF
    for i in range(0, datalen):
        crc = (crc >> 8) | (crc << 8)
        crc = crc ^ data[i]
        crc = crc ^ ((crc & 0xff) >> 4)
        crc = crc ^ ((crc << 8) << 4)
        crc = crc ^ (((crc & 0xff) << 4)<<1)

    return crc
```

returns `FFFF00F030C2B2`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: work on int, but do a `0x0000FFFF` to only consider the first 2 bytes and simulate a short.

Anything nicer?

```py
def compute(data, datalen):
    crc=0x0000FFFF
    for i in range(0, datalen):
        crc = ((crc >> 8) & 0x0000ffff) | ((crc << 8) & 0x0000ffff)
        crc = crc ^ data[i]
        crc = crc ^ (((crc & 0xff) >> 4) & 0x0000ffff)
        crc = crc ^ ((crc << 12) & 0x0000ffff)
        crc = crc ^ (((crc & 0xff) << 5) & 0x0000ffff)

    return crc
```

Comment: After a `<<` operation, you shouldn't need this `&` operation, as long as the input is within the limits.

Answer (score 0):

You can always roll your own class for a 16 bit int.  Obviously, not all of these methods need to be written for your case, and I omitted a few as well.

```py
class UShort:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = int(x) & 0xffff

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<UShort {}>'.format(self._x)

    @classmethod
    def to_short(cls, x):
        return cls(int(x) & 0xffff)

    @property
    def hex(self):
        return hex(self._x)

    def __add__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x + self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __sub__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x - self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __mul__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x * self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __div__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x / self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __mod__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x % self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __pow__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x ** self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __and__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x & self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __xor__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x ^ self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __or__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x | self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __lshift__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x << self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __rshift__(self, other): return self.to_short(self._x >> self.to_short(other)._x)
    def __radd__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x + self._x)
    def __rsub__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x - self._x)
    def __rmul__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x * self._x)
    def __rdiv__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x / self._x)
    def __rmod__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x % self._x)
    def __rpow__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x ** self._x)
    def __rand__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x & self._x)
    def __rxor__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x ^ self._x)
    def __ror__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x | self._x)
    def __rlshift__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x << self._x)
    def __rrshift__(self, other): return self.to_short(self.to_short(other)._x >> self._x)
    def __int__(self): return int(self._x)
    def __float__(self): return float(self._x)
    def __neg__(self): return self.to_short(self._x.__neg__())
    def __pos__(self): return self
    def __abs__(self): return self
    def __invert__(self): return self.to_short(self._x.__invert__())
```

And then just modify your computer to use the new class.

```py
def compute(data, datalen):
    crc=UShort(0xFFFF)
    for i in range(0, datalen):
        crc = (crc >> 8) | (crc << 8)
        crc = crc ^ data[i]
        crc = crc ^ ((crc & 0xff) >> 4)
        crc = crc ^ ((crc << 8) << 4)
        crc = crc ^ (((crc & 0xff) << 4)<<1)

    return crc.hex

data = [0x8c, 0x4c]
compute(data, 2)
# returns:
'0xcab2'
```

Comment: interesting. A bit similar to mine, but it's neater with a class.